# Civicrm Event Info Page has Register, iCal, and iCal feed buttons too close to each other

Tags: wordpress, civievent, smarty

I'm using CiviCRM with wordpress for first time, but the same "issue" exists with Drupal. The bottom "Register Now" button on the info page for an event is very close to two more buttons for downloading iCal info for event, and accessing iCal feed for the event.

We're finding that fat-fingered folks on tablets are hitting one or the other of these buttons, then getting confused and giving up. Is there a setting in the UI to either not have these buttons, if I just want to provide more spacing, do I need to edit something in the backend? If the latter, could someone point me to the particular file?

(and is this a smarty template modification that I need to make and then keep updated?)

[image: ical button close to register button]

Comment: I had searched for a similar question and didn't find any, but there was a thread from 2008 that ended with a reference to the template files where the ical buttons existed. I'll take a look at these and see if I can find where to modify. I'd still like to know if iCal can be disabled from the UI. 

civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.tpl
comment out lines 95-100

civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Page/ThankYou.tpl
comment out lines 120-125

civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/ReceiptMessage.tpl
comment out lines 48-49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add CSS, either to `civicrm.css` or to your site's theme, that adds space between them.

If there aren't any CSS selectors specific enough for that, you could add *those* to the template, and submit that as a patch to upstream CiviCRM.  It would be a welcome addition, and would then be the standard in future versions of CiviCRM, which removes the maintenance burden from you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it is easy to do with minor edits to the code (a template). I edited the following smarty template:

wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Page/iCalLinks.tpl

I commented out lines 10 to 16, which is the entire executable for this file.

This gets rid of the two badges under the edit button, and solved this problem for fat-fingered folks.

**I still wonder if there's anything in the CiviCRM UI that would do the same thing without editing the template..**

Thanks All in advance.

WordPress 5.6, CiviCRM 5.32.1

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.tpl#L219-L223 where the EventInfo template includes the iCalLinks template you will see that it is conditional on `$event.is_public`

So if you untick the 'Public Event' checkbox on the 'Info and Settings' tab then those iCal links go away.

However, that also has a couple of other effects which may or may not be a problem for you.  From the help text:

> Public Events
>
> When enabled, this event will be included in iCalendar feeds and
> displayed on your site's "Upcoming Events" block.

Alternatively you could add some css to increase the spacing between the Register Now button and the iCal links, or jQuery to hide them.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. My particular issue is with some unsophisticated users who need a signup process that can't lead them astray. Taking away the iCal feed for them isn't an issue because they wouldn't use it in all likelihood. I need to keep the event public so that a login isn't required to register for an event. This particular installation is predicated on most contacts never becoming users of the front end - that is they would for the most part never login to the website because we're using it mostly for events AND as a membership tracking database.

Comment: Note that you don't need to login to register for an event that is not 'public'. Public affects inclusion in some listings but does not affect anonymous users registering (although that might be more useful!)